# ASP.NET Web API - method that is called for all requests prior to the routed method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing in C# for ASP.NET Web API 2. What I want is a catch-all method that will execute for every single request that comes to my Web API.

If the method returns null, then the original routing should continue, seeking out the correct method. However, if the method returns, say, an HTTPResponseMessage, the server should return that response and not proceed on to normal routing.

The use case would be the ability to handle various scenarios that may impact the entire API. For example: ban a single IP address, block (or whitelist) certain user agents, deal with API call counting (e.g. someone can only make X requests to *any* API method in Y minutes).

The only way I can imagine to do this right now is to literally include a method call in each and every new method I write for my API. For example,

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage myNewMethod()
{
    // I want to avoid having to do this in every single method.
    var check = methodThatEitherReturnsResponseOrNull(Request);
    if (check != null) return (HttpResponseMessage)check;

    // The method returned null so we go ahead with normal processing.
    ...
}
```

Is there some way to accomplish this in routing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what Action Filters are for. These are Attributes that you can place either globally, at the class (Controller), or at the method (Action) levels. These attributes can do preprocessing where you execute some code before your action executes or post processing where you execute code after the action executes.

When using pre processing you have the option to return a result to the caller and not have your method (action) be fired at all. This is good for model validation, authorization checks, etc.

To register a filter globally edit the `WebApiConfig.cs` file.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new YourFilterAttribute()); // add record
        // rest of code
    }
}
```

To create a custom attribute inherit from `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute` or you can implement interface `System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter` or you can implement `IAuthorizationFilter`/`AuthorizationFilterAttribute` if you specifically want to allow/deny a request.

It also sounds like you want to create multiple attributes, one for each role like IP filtering or count calling etc. That way it would be more modular instead of one enormous authorization filter.

There are many tutorials out there like [this one](https://damienbod.com/2014/01/04/web-api-2-using-actionfilterattribute-overrideactionfiltersattribute-and-ioc-injection/) (*chosen at random in my Google search results*). I am not going to post code because you did not do so either so I would just be guessing as to what you wanted to do.